# Having issues intergrating Unit Testing into an active Vuetify 2 Project, Error with SASS (Mocha-webpack / Vue Unit Test Tools)

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuetify.js

When trying to run a Unit Test on a Vuetify 2 app I get the error for SASS Stylesheets not being found, they are there.

The app has had no unit testing before so we need to include it to this project, I have tried to create a new fresh project and the testing works perfectly there, I have used multiple guides such as: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/unit-testing But I get the same issues no matter what I use. I have tried mocha, mocha-webpack, chai, vue-test-utils, Jest etc.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1YNu.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Ejm.jpg

Does not work

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Tabs from '@/components/ui/Tabs.vue'

let wrapper = shallowMount(Tabs);
console.log(wrapper);
describe('Tabs.vue', () => {
  it('current tab equals empty', () => {
    // wrapper.vm.clearValue();
    expect(wrapper.vm.currentTab).to.equal('');
  });
});
```

Works

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'

describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {
  it('renders props.msg when passed', () => {
    const msg = 'new message'
    const wrapper = shallowMount(HelloWorld, {
      propsData: { msg }
    })
    expect(wrapper.text()).to.include(msg)
  })
})
```

Also tried the code examples here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/unit-testing
They do not work also.

I expect the tests to actually run and either return success or failed. I actually get an error for each of the stylesheets using SASS.